# Show that $x\longmapsto \int_{\mathbb R^n}\frac{f(y)}{|x-y|^{n-\alpha }}dy$ is integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, harmonic-analysis

**Q1)** Let $f\in \mathcal C_c^\infty (\mathbb R^n)$ and $0<\alpha <\frac{n}{2}$. I want to show that $$\int_{\mathbb R^n}\frac{f(y)}{|x-y|^{n-\alpha }}dy$$
is integrable, i.e. that $$\int_{\mathbb R^n}\int_{\mathbb R^n}\frac{|f(y)|}{|x-y|^{n-\alpha }}dxdy <\infty,$$
but unfortunately I didn't succeed. My idea was to use Hardy-Littlewood Sobolef inequality, i.e.
$$\left|\int_{\mathbb R^n}\int_{\mathbb R^n}\frac{f(x)f(y)}{|x-y|^\lambda }dydy\right|\leq C\|f\|_{L^p}\|f\|_{L^q},$$
whenever $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{\lambda }{n}+\frac{1}{q}=2,$
but since it's $\int_{\mathbb R^n}\int_{\mathbb R^n}\frac{f(y)}{|x-y|^\lambda }dydx$ and not $\int_{\mathbb R^n}\int_{\mathbb R^n}\frac{f(y)f(x)}{|x-y|^\lambda }dydx,$ my argument fail. Also I tried to majorate $$\int_{\mathbb R^n}\left|\int_{\mathbb R^n}\frac{f(y)}{|x-y|^\lambda }\right|dydx\quad \text{by}\quad \left|\int_{\mathbb R^n}\int_{\mathbb R^n}\frac{f(y)f(x)}{|x-y|^\lambda }dydx\right|,$$
but unfortunately without success. Any idea ?

**Q2)** By the way, is there a way to proof that it's not integrable if $\alpha \geq \frac{n}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let the Riesz potential $$I_\alpha f(x) =\int_{\Bbb R^n}\frac{f(y)}{|x-y|^{n-\alpha }}dy$$

Note $$(I_\alpha f, g) = \int_{\Bbb R^n}\int_{\Bbb R^n}\frac{f(y)g(x)}{|x-y|^{n-\alpha }}dydx$$

and we know  by Riesz representation theorem that

$$\|I_\alpha f\|_{q'} =\sup_{\|g\|_q = 1} |(I_\alpha f, g)|$$
Where $\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{q'}=1.$
Whereas by Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev inequality we have

$$|(I_\alpha f, g)| \le C\| f\|_p \| g\|_{q}~~~~~\frac{1}{p}+\frac{\alpha}{n}+\frac{1}{q}=2.$$

Hence
$$\|I_\alpha f\|_{q'} =\sup_{\|g\|_q = 1} |(I_\alpha f, g)|\le C\| f\|_p ~~~~\frac{1}{p}+\frac{\alpha}{n}+1-\frac{1}{q'}=2.$$

Taking $q'=1$,

$$\|I_\alpha f\|_{1} \le  C\| f\|_p ~~~~\frac{1}{p}+\frac{\alpha}{n}=2.$$

Comment: In fact, in my book hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev inequality hold for $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{d-\alpha }{d}+\frac{1}{q}=2$ and not $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{\alpha }{d}+\frac{1}{q}=2$... At the end, I get $\frac{1}{p}=\frac{d+\alpha }{d}$ and thus the condition $\alpha<d/2$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: @MSE look here https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwia_ICx0dXYAhXrJZoKHZmOD60QFggpMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.academia.edu%2F22968114%2FIn%25C3%25A9galit%25C3%25A9_De_Hardy_Litllewood_Sobolev_Hardy_Littlewood_Sobolev_Inequality&usg=AOvVaw2sQN3EtZrHwk3lsfxbQ3Lx

Comment: It's exactly what you wrote in your thesis... you defined $I_\alpha f$ as $\int_{\mathbb R^d}\frac{f(y)}{|x-y|^\alpha }$ and not as $\int_{\mathbb R^d}\frac{f(y)}{|x-y|^{d-\alpha }}dy$. Therefore, it's coherent with my remark, no ?

Comment: @MSE that is just the matter of variable   $\lambda = n-\alpha$ then will see that $0<\lambda<n$ iff $0<\alpha<n$. note the condition $0<\alpha<n$ is more general than your,s

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll check this tomorrow, and of course I'll accept when I'll totally understand :-)

Comment: see the first theorem here /:http://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~lerdos/Stud/khotyakov.pdf

Comment: This document is the same as your. Something really doesn't work in your proof. HLS says that $\int\int \frac{f(x)g(y)}{|x-y|^\lambda }\leq C\|f\|_{L^p}\|g\|_{L^q}$ when $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{d-\alpha }{d}+\frac{1}{q}=2$ (your substitution doesn't change anything on this fact). So here we get that $I_\alpha f$ is integrable when $\frac{1}{p}=\frac{d+\alpha }{d}$. Now I know that $I_\alpha f$ is not integrable when $\alpha \geq 2d$. So if your proof would be true, $I_\alpha f$ is still integrable whenever $\alpha \geq \frac{d}{2}$. Did I missunderstand something ? Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: @MSE you are mixing alpha and lambda in your formulas and contrainst be clear. also please read my previous comment about the change of variables. you may also show your source as well or read the proof in my references and tell me where something went wrong`